# Remove default padding from DropdownButtonFormField2 and resize the width

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have this dropdown list and I want a few things changed, but have no clue how to do so.

1. I want the width of the dropdown to equal the width of the container above. As you can see in the example I provided above, it is not equal and that looks really bad.
2. There is way too much padding in the dropdown options right now. I need everything to be compressed to minimum padding so I can specify the padding I want

Here is my code for the Dropdown FormField, and here is a screenshot

[Thanks!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqtpH.png)

```
                Container(
                  width: size.width * .9,
                  child: DropdownButtonFormField2(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Muscle',
                      filled: true,
                      isDense: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white24,
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    value: selectedMuscleGroup,
                    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedMuscleGroup = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                    items: <String>[
                      'Biceps',
                      'Triceps',
                      'Chest',
                      'Back',
                      'Legs',
                      'Shoulders'
                    ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero, child: Text(value)),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
```

Thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DropdownButtonFormField2` provides flexible options to customize.

**To Manage Padding:**
Overall dropdownPadding can be set via `dropdownStyleData` and
Specific menu padding can be set via `menuItemStyleData`

**To Control Width:**
There is `width` property and `offset` to set overall width of dropdown padding and its position in `dropdownStyleData`.

**For Adding Padding to label**: Use `label` property

**To Add padding to Current selected value (button)**: Use `buttonStyleData`

Example for your case,

Code:

```dart
Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      width: 250,
      child: DropdownButtonFormField2(
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
          /// For Managing Label Padding
          label: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Muscle'),
          ),
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        /// For Managing Select Value Padding
        buttonStyleData: const ButtonStyleData(
          height: 50,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top: 8.0)
        ),
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        dropdownStyleData: const DropdownStyleData(
          width: 250.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0)
        ),
        menuItemStyleData: const MenuItemStyleData(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          height: 36.0,
        ),
        value: selectedMuscleGroup,
        onChanged: (String? newValue) {
          setState(() {
            selectedMuscleGroup = newValue;
          });
        },
        items: <String>['Biceps', 'Triceps', 'Chest', 'Back', 'Legs', 'Shoulders']
            .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: That worked perfectly! One more thing though - I do want padding where it says Muscle and Legs though (so in the top part of the dropdown). How would I do that?

Comment: To add padding for `muscle` (label), you can use `labelWidget` instead of label and wrap the text with padding. To control the button (where `Legs`) use `buttonStyleData`

Comment: By the way I got sidetracked working on something else in the app and didn't really get to read this answer completely - I was trying to implement the change you said into my app but I don't know where to add labelWidget. Do you mind updating the answer code? I am really sorry about this - I will be sure to upvote your answer as thanks!

Comment: just did. Have a look!

Comment: I tried implementing the changes you proposed but that only gave padding to the text 'muscle'. I need it so that the 'Legs' have the padding on it. Is it possible to do that? Thank you so much once again!

Comment: For `Legs` use `buttonStyleData`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `DropdownButtonFormField` in a `ButtonTheme` widget, and set the `alignedDropdown: true` property of the `ButtonTheme` widget.

Comment: I implemented the code you asked and wrapped the dropdownbuttonformfield in the buttontheme widget. That unfortunately did absolutely nothing. Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: Here's the before example: https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zob60621ob70?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart

And here's the example that includes the fix you're after: https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-ztb806zztb90?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart